# What DNS Records should I put to configure postfix?

Tags: server, 20.04, dns, email, postfix

I am following this guide: 
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-postfix-dovecot-and-roundcube-on-ubuntu-20-04

to install `postfix`, `dovecot`, and `RoundCube` on my azure ubuntu VM. I know it is for 20.04, but I think that should work with 18.04 too. Anyway, I have a domain I got from Freenom (I know; it is for testing purposes only) but I don't know what records I should put.

I think I should put an A record pointing to my public IP for `mail.mydomain.tk` and set the hostname to `mail.mydomain.tk` too, but I don't know for sure because in the guide they make it so that I can have an email like `admin@mydomain.tk`, so shouldn't I also put an A record for just `mydomain.tk`? Also, I think you need an MX record if you want to **receive** emails. *So what MX and A records should I put?* Thank you